# org-babel multi-line header var

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to find a way how to conveniently edit(and pass) multi-line arguments to org-babel block.

In the example below, ${name} variable is pretty convenient to edit as inline variable but for ${storyDescription} it becomes very annoying because it could contain dozens of lines(separated by \n) and I would like to manage it like a regular text.

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC http :pretty :var projectId="123" :var name="Test story name"
POST https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/${projectId}/stories
X-TrackerToken: ${token}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": ${name},
  "description": ${storyDescription},
  "current_state": "unstarted",
  "estimate": 1
}
#+END_SRC
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

---

Update.

For now, I'm using the following(dirty) hack in Ruby:

```org
#+name: storyDescription

#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :results value
<<-EOL.gsub("\n", "\\n")
first line
second line
EOL
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: storyDescription
: first line\nsecond line\n
```

it works but I'm happy to accept more clean and idiomatic solution to this.

I'm wondering why there isn't some kind of `BEGIN_SRC text`(org-babel "text" language that's used just for setting long content blocks of plain text).

Comment: Why do you think that your solution is a (dirty) hack? It seems like a pretty elegant solution to me (although I would write it in elisp or python, but that does not make much difference).

Comment: @NickD thanks for your comment. If you want to post elisp version I'll gladly accept it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the given (Ruby) solution is fine: I don't consider it a dirty hack. The same thing can be done in just about any language of course. Particularly, as in my case, if one does not speak Ruby.

Here's a code block in emacs lisp (using the [string library s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el), also available from MELPA):

```el
#+name: desc-lisp
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
(setq x "first line
second line
third line
")

(s-replace "\n" "\\n" x)
#+end_src
```

or in python (with `:results value`):

```python
#+name: desc-python-value
#+begin_src python :results value
x="""first line
second line
third line
"""

return x.replace("\n", "\\n")
#+end_src
```

or in python with `:results output`:

```python
#+name: desc-python-output
#+begin_src python :results output drawer
x="""first line
second line
third line
"""

print(x.replace("\n", "\\n"))
#+end_src
```

or even Ruby using a string to make it congruent to the ones above:

```ruby
#+name: desc-ruby-value
#+begin_src ruby :results value drawer
x = "first line
second line
third line
"
    x.gsub("\n", "\\n")
#+end_src
```

In all cases, we define a string and then apply some transformation to it before returning it (in this case, translating newlines to the two-byte sequence `<backslash>, <n>`). Any transformation could be applied (including the identity transformation). In all the above cases, the output is `first line\nsecond line\nthird line\n`.

An alternative organization that may be slightly more modular is to just return the string untransformed from the code block: any transformation could then be applied in another code block that uses the string, E.g.:

```el
#+name: desc-lisp
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
"first line
second line
third line
"
#+end_src

#+name: desc-transformed
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer :var story=desc-lisp
(s-replace "\n" "\\n" story)
#+end_src


#+name: post-story
#+begin_src shell :var story=desc-transformed
echo $story
#+end_src
```

But all of these are minor variations on the theme which you established in your question.